# ImportError: cannot import name constants

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm trying to run a simple piece of code using pyzmq. I am using Python 2.7 and pyzmq 14.5

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ sudo find /usr -name "*pyzmq*"
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyzmq-14.5.0.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyzmq-14.0.1.egg-info
```

Following is the code i'm trying to run:

```
import zhelpers

context = zmq.Context.instance()
server = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
server.bind("tcp://*:5678")

while (1):
    address, empty, data = server.recv_multipart()

    print("address = %s, data = %d" % (address, int(data)))

    data_i = int(data) + 10
    server.send_multipart([
        address,
        b'',
        str(data_i),
    ])
```

But, I'm getting following error and got no clue how to fix this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reqrep_server.py", line 8, in <module>
    import zhelpers
  File "/home/arun/pyzmq_server/zhelpers.py", line 11, in <module> 
    import zmq
  File "/home/arun/pyzmq_server/zmq/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/home/arun/pyzmq_server/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/arun/pyzmq_server/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/home/arun/pyzmq_server/zmq/backend/select.py", line 27, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/home/arun/pyzmq_server/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context, socket, utils, _poll, _version, _device)
ImportError: cannot import name constants
```

I've copied the whole **zmq** folder and placed it in the level as my .py file.

Please help!

**EDIT:**

I've removed those two versions of pyzmq and reinstalled latest pyzmq (with libzmq bundled this time) as instructed [here](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/wiki/Building-and-Installing-PyZMQ).

```
$ sudo find /usr -name "*pyzmq*"
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyzmq-14.7.0-py2.7.egg-info

$ sudo find /usr -name "*libzmq*"
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.so
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.la
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5.0.0
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libzmq.pc
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/libzmq.so
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/backend/cython/libzmq.pxd
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a
```

But this doesn't solve the problem. I'm getting the same error!

Comment: It looks like you have two versions installed. Try starting over. Remove all pyzmq packages and re-install it (using pip or whatever).

Comment: DON'T copy any Python bundle into your code. It is structured in a specific way and it follows very strict and complex rules when importing. That won't definitely solve the problem, even though it could have looked like so. The error must be otherwhere.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem! You should submit an answer and, when allowed, accept it, so future readers know the problem is solved.

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 20):

I encountered a similar problem. `pip install --upgrade pyzmq` did the trick for me

Comment: Not for me, unfortunately

Comment: ya not worked for me either, anybody found the solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

so, what worked for me in this case is the following solution from Osiris from letsencrypt forum:

1. the problem is that you have 2 versions of certbot (in my case I understood that by command:

`whereis certbot`

the output was like this:

`certbot: /usr/bin/certbot /usr/local/bin/certbot /usr/share/man/man1/certbot.1.gz`

2. then I tried to renew both of them wiht the commands:

`/usr/bin/certbot renew`

`/usr/local/bin/certbot renew`

and I got the error:
`An unexpected error occurred:
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'`


...with the 2nd one!

so, I used the following command to remove this folder:

`sudo rm /usr/local/bin/certbot`

Then the error was gone

Hope that helps

Comment: It works for me when I use the command: sudo rm /usr/local/bin/certbot

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

```
pip install --upgrade pyzmq --user
```

--user is to check for the permissions