# Jupyter Installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

i am quite new into the Jupyter community and want to experience what jupyter has to offer. My knowledge about Jupyter is still quite limited

While I was downloading jupyter and trying to open the jupyter notebook. Errors below were shown to me instead.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Tan
> Caken\anaconda\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in
>
> from notebook.notebookapp import main   File "C:\Users\Tan Caken\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 51, in
>
> from zmq.eventloop import ioloop   File "C:\Users\Tan Caken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq_*init*_.py",
> line 50, in 
> from zmq import backend   File "C:\Users\Tan Caken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend_*init*_.py",
> line 40, in 
> reraise(*exc_info)   File "C:\Users\Tan Caken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py",
> line 34, in reraise
> raise value   File "C:\Users\Tan Caken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend_*init*_.py",
> line 27, in 
> *ns = select_backend(first)   File "C:\Users\Tan Caken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py",
> line 28, in select_backend
> mod = **import**(name, fromlist=public_api)   File "C:\Users\Tan Caken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_*init**.py",
> line 6, in 
> from . import (constants, error, message, context, 
> ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module
> 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import)
> (C:\Users\Tan
> Caken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_*init*_.py)

And I don't know how to solve this problem. I kinda notice the import error that says there is a python thing install beforehand, but other than that. I have no clue on resolve on this.

T

Comment: Hi @Tan, please paste here your script `jupyter-notebook-script.py` or its simple version to understand what is doing there. Is this your script for starting jupyter server? How have you installed jupyter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643383/importerror-cannot-import-name-constants this could help

Comment: Basically i install the newest anaconda. after that when I am trying to open the jupyter notebook via the shortcut and it doesn't work. I saw in some website, you can open jupyter notebook in cmd and this is what happened.

And can I know where can I find jupyter-notebook-script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are imports in your error message that point to

```
C:\Users\TanCaken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38
```

which looks like it is a separate python installation. This is probably causing the issue, since the `zmq` installed for that python distribution is probably not compatible with the `jupyter` installed along anaconda.

Try uninstalling the python version at `C:\Users\TanCaken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38`

Comment: Hello, i cannot seem to find the file/folder that I wanted to uninstall. I try to delete the default python but turns out nothing happened.
Is there any way that I can delete the file/folder?

Comment: The `AppData` Folder is hidden by default. In Explorer you can either 1) got to "View" and check the box "Hidden items" or 2) enter the path directly into the adress bar of the explorer